# Picture link to another website not working HTML

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

Good day! I have this picture link but somehow its not linking when I click on the picture:

```
<div id="image-facebook" class="blok"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DePrael/"></a href></div>
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<div id="image-facebook" class="blok"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DePrael/"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute specifies the URL of the page the link goes to. 
you should write this

> ```
> before 
>    //<a href="https://www.facebook.com/DePrael/"></a href>
> after
>    //<a href="https://www.facebook.com/DePrael/"></a>
> ```